# How do you override Post template when using Query Loop block?

Tags: templates, block-editor

Seems like an impossible task to override how posts are rendered in Query Loop block (grid).

Default block level controls enables styling but not overriding of markup.

I just want to apply HTML5 native accordion markup to Post templates in Query Loop grid. Google didn't provide any point and shoot solution.

Comment: do you mean `<detail>` tags? HTML5 doesn't have accordion markup. Have you tried one of the accordion blocks? You're meant to build things by assembling blocks rather than overriding and replacing blocks

Comment: That is the html5 native markup for accordion or at least similar. Rarely a block meets the needs and markup is less than optimal and there's only control over styling. And most of the accordion solution work manually e.g. one needs to create each accordion by hand and not dynamically based on posts of any type. Control over Query loop block's markup should be a priority since it would enable so much. However, I managed to create my "dynamic accordion" with hackish way of adding HTML blocks inside Query loop block where I open and close tags based on which post data I want to include in them.

Comment: ah the details tag isn't an accordion even though you might be tempted to try and use it as one. The query block itself doesn't have much if any HTML to override, all of that comes from inner/nested/child blocks which could be anything, so if you want to change what's inside a query block you add/remove/edit the blocks inside it

Comment: Well, this poc did what designer had planned. Of course details tag isn't accordion in the nature of it but it does provide very similar and quite usable collapse/expand functionality without js libraries and has fairly good CSS support in terms of making it look and feel per design spec. And yes, perhaps I should dig into core/post-template block and inner/child blocks of it to provide more bulletproof solution. However, this whole block consept is rather new and I haven't found a solid how to guide it in terms of php and/or javascript regarding this kind of situations...